# Logo change with date script

Tags: php, arrays

I just wondered if  anybody can point me in the right direction: I'm looking to make a script whereby the logo on my site changes depending on the date; so for instance a haloween style one soon.

I started off by having 2 arrays, 1 of start dates and 1 of end dates(not sure even if this is the best way!):

```
<?php
$start_dates = array('01/01' => 'New Years',
                     '14/02' => 'Valentine Day',
                     '16/02/2010' => 'Pancake Day',
                     '17/03' => 'St Patricks Day',
                     '01/04' => 'April Fools',
                     '02/04/2010' => 'Easter',
                     '23/04' => 'St Georges Day',
                     '11/06/2010' => 'World Cup',
                     '31/10' => 'Halloween',
                     '05/11' => 'Guy Fawkes',
                     '11/11' => 'Armistice Day',
                     '16/10' => 'Today',
                     '15/12' => 'Christmas');

$end_dates = array( '08/01' => 'New Years',
                    '15/02' => 'Valentine Day',
                    '17/02/2010' => 'Pancake Day',
                    '18/03' => 'St Patricks Day',
                    '02/04' => 'April Fools',
                    '06/04/2010' => 'Easter',
                    '24/04' => 'St Georges Day',
                    '12/07/2010' => 'World Cup',
                    '01/11' => 'Halloween',
                    '06/11' => 'Guy Fawkes',
                    '12/11' => 'Armistice Day',
                    '17/10' => 'Today',
                    '01/01' => 'Christmas');
?>
```

Easy so far...the problemis that I need a way of working out if todays date falls between the start date and end date, then changing the image file name.

Its a long shot but I hope someone would be kind enough to help.

Thanks,
B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this

```
$events = array(
    'New Year' => '01/01 01/08',
    'Pancake Day' => '16/02/2010 17/02/2010',
    //etc
);

echo find_event($events, '16/02');
```

where find_event() is

```
function mdy2time($date) {
    $e = explode('/', $date);
    if(count($e) < 3)
        $e[] = '2010';
    return strtotime("$e[1]-$e[0]-$e[2]");
}

function find_event($events, $date = null) {
    $date = is_null($date) ? time() : mdy2time($date);

    foreach($events as $name => $range) {
        list($start, $end) = explode(' ', $range);
        if($date >= mdy2time($start) && $date <= mdy2time($end))
            return $name;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use an array more like this:

```
$dates = array();
$dates[] = array(
    'name' => 'New Years'
    'start' = '01/14',
    'end' => '01/20',
    'style' => 'haloween',
);
$dates[] = array(
    //...
);
```

then you can get the style as follows:

```
$style='default';

// date as number e.g. 130 (january 30th)
$currDate = date('md',time()) * 1;
foreach ($dates AS $k => $v) {
    $tmp = explode("/",$v['start'];
    $start = ($tmp[1].$tmp[0])*1;
    $tmp = explode("/",$v['end'];
    $stop = ($tmp[1].$tmp[0])*1;
    if ($start <= $currDate && $currDate < $stop) {
        $style=$v['style'];
        break;
    }
}

echo 'style: '.$style;
```

Didn't check the code yet, so feel free to correct me if iam wrong.